# Remove index.php on a windows server

Tags: htaccess, server, windows

I have EE installed on a clients windows server but I'm having problems removing index.php from the URL

This is the first time I've worked on a windows server (all precious jobs have been in apache and used .htaccess)

The hosting company is being incredibly difficult - can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

James

Comment: Did my answer below work for you?

Comment: This has been a common question before. Let us know which answer worked for, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Which hosting provider do you use? What version of IIS/Windows do they use?

You can try to add a web.config file to your root

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{R:1}" pattern="\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
<security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hosting is with Redstation

Answer (score 0):

[ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) might be helpful, I've seen it used on a few windows hosts.

> The hosting company is being incredibly difficult

Maybe recommend your client moves to a new host?

Comment: Have suggested that but they are reluctant to move. Plus I'm working through another agency so it starts to get difficult as I don't have direct access to the client. Will try  ISAPI